# How do i move a SharePoint Online site to another Sharepoint online account

Tags: move

Have developed an application developed in Access and published to SharePoint Online. Now want to deploy to a customer site where they will have their own SharePoint online account.

Answer (score 0):

Access has it's own built in functionality for creating deployment packages. Simply open your App in access, and go to File->Save As.

You can then choose "Deployment" which will build a .app package for you, which you can then deploy to your customer's site.

You can even publish it to the SharePoint App Store if you'd like.

Comment: The site is based on a access database that has been published to SharePoint not a "web app" as such. When I try to save as a package I'm prompted to supply a digital signature and do not have one currently available. Any advice on how do I create a digital signature for use in packaging the Access application?

Comment: Have sourced a digital signature and "packaged" the application within Access. When upackaging the sharepoint data tables are still utilised to hold the data so can't see how this helps in moving the site to another sharepoint online account.